# EXCEL: AND Statement

Tags: excel, formulas

How do I say "If both words 'menu' and 'training' are in found in a range of cells?"

Excel says the formula below uses too many arguments.

The L column contains cells with paragraphs of words. I want a formula that proves TRUE if and only if the cell contains BOTH WORDS.

```
=if(and(isnumber(search("menu", L2:L4547))), (isnumber(search("training", L2:L4547))), "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNTIF()`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(L2:L4547,"menu"),COUNTIF(L2:L4547,"training")),"Both found","not found")
```

Perhaps a little counterintuitive, but `SEARCH` only looks in a single cell (AFAIK). Using `COUNTIF()`, you can do a range.

Comment: I was going to go with isnumber(match()). But you may want to use wildcards on the strings.  I believe the OP is searching part of a string.

Comment: Oh and if the OP wrapped the isnumber(Search()) in SUMPRODUCT() each, it would have worked.  But that is the long way around to get to the same thing as you have.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much!

Comment: (@AndrewWolfe - If that solves it, you can mark it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.)

Comment: @ScottCraner- Yeah, there are a few ways to do that, and I wasn't sure if OP needed wildcards or not.  Good comment!

Comment: Well actually, it runs, which is great! But it never return TRUE if both words are found in a cell. Is this code supposed to return TRUE only if both countif functions return TRUE?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe can you clarify how your data is laid out and what you expect? Adding clarification to your OP would help.

Comment: Yes. Check above and tell me what you think.